# Чаю vs. чая: what ending is correct?

Tags: падежи, склонение, окончания

Is `чаю` or `чая` more correct in the sentences

> Я бы не отказался от чашки ча*

and

> Можно мне ещё ча*?

and what's the grammatical explanation?

Comment: Надо на кофе переходить, там все просто :)

Comment: «Как правильно: „чашку коньяку“ или „чашку коньяка“?» — «Правильно — рюмку».

Comment: Мы уже сами запутались =). И так и так верно.

Comment: Еще в чай или кофе можно подсыпать сахарного песка или песку.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Это пример так называемого [частичного падежа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) (партитива). В русском языке он используется редко и в основном с существительными, обозначающими еду или напитки.

> Выпить воды (не всю воду, а немножко воды)
>
> Поесть хлеба
>
> Выпить коньяку

Частичный падеж по форме обычно совпадает с родительным, но многие существительные мужского рода, такие как, например, чай, коньяк, бензинчик, и т.п., имеют две формы частичного падежа:  чая/чаю, коньяка/коньяку, бензинчика/бензинчику. Оба варианта правильные, но последний (который совпадает по форме с дательным) более разговорный.

Таким образом, в случае второго предложения

> Можно мне ещё ча*?

оба варианта правильные, так как здесь используется партитив. В случае же первого предложения мы имеем дело с обычным родительным падежом и, следовательно, правильно будет

> Я бы не отказался от чашки чая.

Comment: My God, is this yet *another* Russian case?!  Couldn't it also be considered as a special form of the genitive?

Comment: @z7sgѪ: It *is* considered as a special form of genitive

Comment: Осталось понять, почему хлеба, но чаю и какие слова относятся к исключениям. А нельзя сказать `я хочу ещё коньяка`?

Comment: @texnic: Я может поспешил с предположением, что у слова коньяк ч.п. будет только коньяку. По ходу там тоже кажется две версии. Чем дальше я думаю, тем больше склоняюсь к тому, что почти у всех существительных м.р. две версии ч.п. Я еще подумаю и покапаюсь и отредактирую свой ответ.

Comment: @texnic: посоветовался с профессором по русскому языку в университете и отредактировал ответ

Comment: Russian has 15 cases actually. But officially they teach only six.

Comment: @Anixx: Which are they. Apart from the traditional six, I am aware of the vocative, partitive, and locative. What are the other six?

Comment: Create a question and I will answer.

Comment: @Anixx: I did. http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/404/the-less-known-russian-cases

Comment: This answer is really a comprehensive one, but to make it easier to understand, I would say that **чаю** can be translated as ***some*** tea.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте окончание -я в любой ситуации, ошибки не будет.
Окончание -ю можно считать устаревшим, встречается в литературе до 70-ходов XX века или как ироничное в разговорной речи, при имитации речи жителя дореволюционной России, например, *"А не испить ли нам чаю?"*

То же самое касается *коньяк-а* и *коньяк-у*, используйте родительный падеж и не ошибётесь.

Comment: Interesting, could you please provide more data that supports your statement that the ending -ю in such cases is obsolete? You could use [the Russian National Corpus](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/). Thank you

Comment: In addition to Olga's comment, please provide answers in English to questions asked in English and answer in Russian to questions in Russian.  Please see our [FAQ](http://russian.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to @Kirill's answer. According to the orthographic reform of Russian language in 1956:

> <...>
>
> Quantitative word-forms in Genitive and Accusative cases
>
> <...>
>
> After 1956:  Nowadays, forms ending with *“-у", "-ю"* are used less and less frequently.

[Wikipedia: Russian Orthography before 1956](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE_1956_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.B8_.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.B9)

Hence the correct modern form is:

> Я бы не отказался от чашки чая.
> Можно мне ещё чая?

Answer (score -3):

Correct form: Я хочу чашку чаЮ, but if you want some tea you should say: Я хочу чаЯ. If you mention about quantity tea or cognac you should use form чаЮ or коньякУ, if you don't tell about how many tea or cognac you want, you should use form чаЯ/коньякА.

Comment: It's exactly the other way around: чашка чая, выпить чаю.

Comment: You don't seem to be answering the question correctly.  Note that you can _edit_ your answer if you realise it's wrong by using the link below it.