# What are the lesser known Russian cases?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

In schools, it is taught that Modern Russian has 6 cases:

> - Nominative (Именительный)
> - Genitive (Родительный)
> - Dative (Дательный)
> - Accusative (Винительный)
> - Instrumental (Творительный)
> - Prepositional (Предложный)

Here on RLU, there are mentions of other lesser-known cases that are perhaps not universally accepted as full-blown cases of Modern Russian, but sure have their peculiarities.

> - The Vocative(Звательный) and Neo-Vocative. (Mentioned in the question [Миш, Кать, Ань, пап, мам — what is it in an address?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/195/71))
> - The Partitive(Частичный). mentioned [in this answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/194/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%8E-vs-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-what-ending-is-correct/196#196) by myself.

There's also the so-called

> - The Locative Case (Местный Падеж)

that is usually united with the Prepositional Case, but for many words differs in form. E.g.

> о лесе (Prep.) - в лесу(Loc.)
>   о саде (Prep.) - в саду(Loc.)

So, what are other lesser-known cases? [A comment by Anixx](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/194/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%8E-vs-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-what-ending-is-correct/196#comment872_196) goes as far as to claim there are 15 cases in Russian. It would be interesting and useful to list them in one place.

Comment: Added one more, totally 16.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The most extensive list is as follows (totally, 16):

1. **Именительный (Nominative)**
2. **Родительный  (Genitive)**
3. **Отделительный (Частичный) (Partitive)**

   > хочу выпить весь чай (Accusative)
   >
   > хочу выпить немного чаю (Partitive)
4. **Ждательный**

   > жду письмо (Accusative), отправленное вчера
   >
   > жду письма (Ждательный) от мамы
5. **Дательный (Dative)**
6. **Счетный I (Numerative I)**

   > на этой шкале нет граммов (Genitive)
   >
   > пуля весит девять грамм (Numerative)
7. **Счетный II (Numerative II)**

   > не прошло и ча́са (Genitive)
   >
   > это заняло три часа́ (Numerative)
8. **Винительный (Accusative)**
9. **Включительный (Превратительный) (Translative)**

   > стрелять в президента (Accusative)
   >
   > избрать в президенты (Translative)
10. **Творительный (Instrumental)**
11. **Предложный (Prepositional)**
12. **Местный (Locative)**

    > в лесе (Prepositional) много пользы
    >
    > в лесу (Locative) растут грибы
13. **Исходный (Ablative)**

    > гулял в лесý (Locative)
    >
    > вышел и́з лесу (Ablative) (difference in the stress)
14. **Лишительный (Abessive)**

    > ни дня без строчки (Genitive)
    >
    > ни единого разу (Abessive)
15. **Звательный старый (Old Vocative)**

    > господь (Nominative) бог
    >
    > господи, боже мой (Old Vocative)
16. **Звательный новый (Neo-Vocative)**

    > хороший дядя (Nominative)
    >
    > дядь, пойдём (Neo-Vocative)

Note that no source gives them all, but all of them can be found in at least some sources.

If you ask me, I would accept only a few of them:

**1. Nominative**

**1a. Vocative** (new Vocative only)

**2. Genitive**

**2a. Partivive** (-у,-ю-Genitive, also including Abessive and Ждательный listed above)

**2b. Numerative** (special use for units of measurement)

**3. Dative**

**4. Accusative**

**5. Instrumental**

**6. Prepositional**

**6a. Locative**

In sum, 10.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I was wondering if there was any logic in the order of the cases you listed or it's just random.

Comment: One more point. What is the real distinction between Partitive and Abessive? Seems like it's the same thing

Comment: Some define a separate case for what is normally considered pl. gen. in *щец*, *дровец*

Comment: What is "щец, дровец"? I do not know such words.

Comment: @Armen, I agree with you, they are very similar. And also the Ждательный. They convey the meaning of definite/indefinite article.

Comment: @Anixx: *налей-ка мне щец да наруби дровец*. Those are diminutives of *щи* (cabbage soup) and *дрова* (firewood)

Comment: @Quassnoi I think it is deminutive. Like in дело - дельце.

Comment: @Anixx: yes but they have no other forms except pl. gen. Some consider them not separate words but a special case of *щи* and *дрова* instead.

Comment: @OlgaNikitina: `14` is just a bad example. Abessive is found in forms *ни разу*, *ни часу*, *ни шагу* (genitive in dative form).

Comment: @Quassnoi: You could also add 17. for щец and дровец if you know the name of the case... I mean, the more, the better :)

Comment: @Quassnoi: Also, would you by any chance know the latin name for Ждательный?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: I don't know the name, and only remember reading about it once (in *Русская Речь* I believe)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: *ждательный* was coined by Zaliznyak in Russian and for Russian.

Comment: this only question and this only answer already is a valuable contribution for Russian Linguistics internet resources. Awesome.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan the order here is something illogical, yes. I guess the best one is to list mainly 6 basic cases in standard order, each followed by its "deviations", and then follow by vocatives (which are listed in historic grammars after other cases). Also better was to use basic number with suffixes, e.g. 2 for genitive => 2a for partitive, 2b, 2c for numeratives. Also, other sources could use reverse order of numeratives (I for singular, II for plural).

Comment: Let me leave here a link to a [wonderful blog post](http://ilyabirman.ru/meanwhile/2006/10/01/2/) by Ilya Birman (it's in Russian).

Comment: @Netch vocative is a "deviation" of nomenative.

Comment: Whenever I hear  about vocative case, I think of Carrol's Alice in WOnderland (and I'm russian, lol)

Comment: Sixty years ago Uspenski wrote an article that mentions most of the cases listed above and also attempts to provide a mathematically precise definition of 'case':  [Успенский В. А. К определению падежа по А. Н. Колмогорову](http://www.kolmogorov.info/uspensky-k_opredeleniyu_padezha_po_kolmogorovu.html)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan I amended the answer to address your question about order and about similarity between partitive and abessive (I also think they are quite similar)

Comment: during my school years they told me there were just 6 ;-(

Comment: @SergeySlepov  The link you provide no longer appears to be a good one.  If you can replace it, great.  If not, perhaps this link [**here**](http://fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/452/Kolmogorov%20And%20Mathematical%20Logic.pdf) will suffice (especially for those of you whose Russian isn't quite good enough to read an academic article of this nature in Russian).

Comment: @LisaBeck, Here is another copy of the same article: [Успенский В. А. К определению падежа по А. Н. Колмогорову](http://lab314.brsu.by/kmp-lite/CL/CL-Lect/Case-ANK.htm)

Comment: @SergeySlepov  That one works!  Спасибо!

Answer (score 11):

Another instance of extended cases list I've saved from FidoNet echoareas (which aren't stably archived at WWW resources so are continually lost).

It differs from the list posted by Anixx in the following:

1. In presence of 3 vocatives but miss of Ablative.
2. I have regroupped these cases according to traditional order of 6 main cases used in school grammars, and others which differs from their "bases" only for some words are listed as subvariants (e.g. (2a) is variant of (2)). I treat this order as more useful because it simplifies learning.

(I'm currently editing it, not for contents, but for form, so one can see intermediate partially edited variants.)

-1. **Именительный (Nominative)**

-2. **Родительный (Genitive)**

-2a. **Количественно-отделительный (Родительный-II)**
(ложка сахару, налейте мне чаю vs. нет сахара, пять пачек чая)

-2b. **Счётный-I**
(два шага́, часа́, ряда́ vs. (Род. ед.): ша́га, ча́са, ря́да; в разговорном также - два раза́)

It is used for some words with numerals like 2-4, 22-24, etc. instead of Sing. Gen. and differs only in stress placement.

-2c. **Счётный-II**
(чулок — чулков, сапог — сапогов, гусар — гусаров, вольт — вольтов, грамм —
граммов, байт — байтов)

It is used for some words with numerals like 5-20, 25-30, etc. instead of Pl. Gen. and differs in style of endings forming. There is no single rule for it, but there are a few patterns.

-3. **Дательный (Dative)**

-4. **Винительный (Accusative)**

-4a. **Включительный**

(взять в солдаты, в зятья; выйти в люди; пройти в кандидаты)

It is grammatically equal to old Pl. Acc. and used for one stable pattern. The difference with the current Acc. is that it is identical in forms with Pl. Nom.

-5. **Творительный (Instrumental)**

-6. **Предложный (Prepositional)**

-6a. Местный aka Предложный-II (Locative)
(в лесу́, в крови́, в слеза́х vs. о ле́се, о кро́ви, о слёзах)

-7a. Звательный-I (церковнославянский)
Боже, господи, владыко, отче

-7b. **Звательный-II (старый)**

деда, доча, сынка

-7c. **Звательный-III (новый)**

-8. **Ждательный**
(жду письма, мать, результата — внешне всегда совпадает с Род. или Вин.)

-9. **Лишительный**
(нет читал газеты vs. газету — внешне всегда совпадает с Род. или Дат.)

дядь, мам, Лен, тёть, Солнц, ребят, девчат, батянь.

```
этот список я собрал, начитавшись обсуждения здесь и полазив по интернету за
опубликованными лингвистами, так что вот еще и ссылочки для полноты:

1: Зализняк А.А. "Русское именное словоизменение." Москва.: Hаука, 1967.
2: Успенский В.А. "К определению падежа по А. H .Колмогорову //
Бюллетень объединения по проблемам машинного перевода." . том 5.
http://www.kolmogorov.pms.ru/uspensky-k_opredeleniyu_padezha_po_kolmogorovu
3. Клобуков Е.В. "Семантика падежных форм в современном русском
литературном языке. (Введение в методику позиционного анализа)"
Москва, изд МГУ, 1986.
4: Милославский И.Г., "Морфология // Современный русский язык / Под ред.
В. А. Белошапковой". 2е изд.. М.: Высшая школа, 1989.
```

Also I'm citing groundings for some cases, from the same discussion:

```
*Ждательный падеж* представлен однопадежным рядом именных словоформ,
встречающихся в оборотах _жду мать, жду результата, жду поезд, жду
поезда, жду письмо, жду письма_ и им подобных. Здесь существенно, что в
этом ряду отсутствуют такие обороты, как _жду матери_ и _жду результат,_
которые объявляются недопустимыми; если же допустить такие обороты, то
ждательного падежа не возникнет, а окажется просто-напросто, что после
глагола _ждать_ всегда возможен как винительный, так и родительный падеж
(по аналогичной причине в схеме Зализняка отсутствует лишительный падеж,
о чём будет сказано ниже). Ждательный падеж не возникнет и в том случае,
если признать актуальным почти стёртое ныне архаичное смысловое различие
между оборотами вида _ждать письмо_ и _ждать письма;_ в этом случае
также окажется, что после глагола _ждать_ возможен как винительный, так
и родительный падеж -- но не по произволу, как в предыдущем случае,
а в зависимости от степени определённости предмета; именно, для
определённого предмета будет употребляться винительный падеж, а для
неопределённого -- родительный (возможно, что "письмо" со значением
определённости и "письмо" со значением неопределённости целесообразно
считать разными лексемами).

Теперь о *включительном падеже.* В этом падеже предположительно
пребывают словоформы _солдаты_ и _зятья_ в контекстах _идти в солдаты_
и _взять в зятья._ Слово "предположительно" означает, что включительный
падеж возникает при выполнении следующих двух предположений.
Предполагается, во-первых, что в указанных контекстах словоформы
_солдаты_ и _зятья_ принадлежат тем же лексемам, что и словоформы
_солдат_ и _зять,_ -- а не особым лексемам, означающим нерасчленённые
совокупности солдат или зятьёв; при этой противоположной точке зрения
падеж имён в рассматриваемых контекстах окажется винительным или
именительным. Предполагается, во-вторых, что присутствующие в указанных
контекстах смысловые отношения тождественны тем, которые присутствуют
в словосочетаниях _идти в армию_ и _взять в семью;_ при отрицании этого
второго предположения (но принятии первого) падеж имён оказывается
именительным (причём именительным с предлогом!).

В моей статье в качестве возможного был назван также "лишительный
падеж". В схеме А. А. Зализняка он отсутствует. Дело в том, что
определение А. А. Зализняка, помимо многочисленных технических
улучшений, отличается от определения, изложенного в моей статье, в
одном принципиальном пункте. А именно, определение Зализняка запрещает
считаться самостоятельным падежом такому претенденту на это звание,
у которого множество соответствующих этому претенденту сегментов
является объединением других множеств, каждое из которых образует свой
собственный падеж. А множество сегментов "лишительного падежа" как
раз и является объединением двух множеств, одно из которых отвечает
винительному падежу, а другое родительному: в приведённом в [РИС] в
качестве примера контексте _"я не узнал..."_ вместо многоточия можно
по произволу поставить слово как в винительном, так и в родительном
падеже. Таким образом, определение Зализняка содержит дополнительную
запретительную клаузулу, но зато даёт более экономную картину: вместо
того, чтобы вводить в рассмотрение двенадцатый, лишительный падеж,
достаточно сказать, что в определённых контекстах можно употреблять как
винительный, так и родительный падеж.
```

Comment: ну вот вы то не новичок, в отличие от потока однобальников. У вас на Unix&Linux SE полтыщи. Неужели вы сами не понимаете, почему, чем именно ваш ответ плох? Что он ничего нового не даёт, по сравнению с предыдущим ответом? Что в нём много воды? Что он отформатирован ужасно?

Comment: @shabunc Согласен только с упрёком по форматированию, но считаю это второстепенным фактором (для данного случая). В отсутствие изложения списка от гарантированно авторитетного источника все разногласия должны быть рассмотрены и изучены, а я не считаю себя Зализняком:) и Anixx сам сказал, что у него свод из разных источников, а мой вариант отличается в достаточно заметных деталях. Будет окончательный авторитетный источник - я спокойно сотру свой вариант. Но пока этого нет - Ваши претензии бессмысленны.

Comment: так и укажите, в каких деталях отличается, а не предлагайте прочитать простыню скопипасченого текста.

Comment: Я указал в самом начале. Вы как-то странно читаете, пропуская основное.

Comment: ваше право, всё, что я пытался донести, что если вы бы вложили чуть больше усилий в этот ответ, а не вставили бы копписастом письмо вместе (!!!) с заголовками, вы бы с больше верноятностью набрали бы за вопрос баллов.

Comment: @shabunc я его доредактирую, там безусловно есть что править. Возможно, я поспешил отправить вначале "сырую" версию, но это исправится. А заголовки - я их счёл существенным для указания источника, для которого уже невозможно найти URL.

Comment: Please could you remove the part of your answer that repeats the answer of other people and only leave your contribution? It would also be nice if you could introduce more structure into your answer, separating your texts into topics? Something like "there is also case A, it's meaning is X, here is an example, here is the source where it is described". Thank you.