# What are some examples of nouns that end in -у in prepositional case

Tags: падежи, окончания

I know one already:

```
in the garden - в саду
```

Comment: Lawrence, please avoid asking lists, they are highly discouraged in the SE network. I'm leaving this open for now since there are only two answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
in the forest - в лесу
in the nose - в носу
in the heaven - в раю
in the year - в году
in the cupboard - в шкафу
in snow - в снегу
in delirium - в бреду
in common use, widespread - в ходу
in the brain - в мозгу
in ice - во льду
in the mouth - во рту
in the formation - в строю
```

We study 6 cases at school, and things like this we call exceptions. However, this is *locative case* from old Russian. Did you notice all these nouns describe *where*, they point at the location of object?

And a tricky example:

```
В "Вишнёвом саде" Чехов рассказывает о ...
```

Locative forms are not used when the noun is a part of a name of a work.

If your understanding of Russian permits, you may read an [article](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA#.D0.A0.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9.C2.A0.E2.80.94_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.B2.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.B9) about other "hidden" cases that are often considered exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

The ones that come first to my mind (apart from already mentioned) are:

```
    в aду (in Hell)
    на балу (at the dance party)
    на бегу (while running)
    на берегу (on the shore)
    на боку (on the side)
    в бору (in the pine forest)
    в бою (in the battle)
    на валу (on the bank)
    на возу (on the cart)
    в/на глазу (in/on the eye)
    в году (in the year)
    на [своём] горбу (on [somebody's own] hump, used figuratively = bring something with your own muscles without any help of mechanisms or other people)
    на Дону (in the Don region)
    в жиру (in the fat)
    в зобу (in the craw)
    на кону (at stake)
    в/на краю (in the region/on the edge)
    в кругу (in the circle, mostly used figuratively f.e. в кругу друзей - among friends)
    на лету (while flying, mostly used figuratively = doing something fast and at the same time with something else)
    во/на льду (in/on the ice)
    в мозгу (in the brain, but anatomically speaking we say "в мозге")
    на мосту (on the bridge)
    на мысу (on the cape)
    в/на носу (in/on the nose)
    на плаву (afloat)
    в плену (in captivity)
    в/при полку (in/attached to the regiment)
    в порту (in the port)
    в поту (all over in sweat)
    в раю (in heaven, in paradise)
    во рту (in the mouth)
    на скаку (while riding)
    на слуху (if a person is на слуху, it means he is talked about a lot)
    в/на снегу (in/on the snow)
    в строю (in the formation, in the line-up)
    в/на углу (in/on the corner)
    в хлеву (in the barn)
    в/на ходу (the one which is being commonly used/while moving)
    в/на шкафу (in/on top of the wardrobe)
```

There are more of them, it's rather hard for me to remember more :D.

Comment: I will add more examples to your answer and I suggest that all other people try to add to one of the existing answers rather than posting their own answers.

Comment: Added some and sorted them alphabetically.

Answer (score 6):

I added some more examples of nouns ending with *-у* in the prepositional (aka locative) case to the Yellow Sky's answer (pending peer's review). There are many more of them still not mentioned.

In this answer I would like to concentrate on the phenomenon of such words, finding common patterns in them, and suggesting the ways of finding them instead of just listing them. Kind of following the Chinese proverb: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime. :-)

### Common pattern

I noticed that for all these words the following is true:

1. An old Russian word
2. Masculine gender, ending with consonant
3. Used in the extended meaning of location inside of something
4. Prepositional case is formed by taking the Dative case of the same word and moving the stress to the ending "*-у*".

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think in the Old Russian almost all the nouns had such form. With time these forms started to be supplanted by more modern forms of prepositional (locative) case but some words resisted and are still keeping their old forms in certain meanings. This my hypothesis is confirmed by the fact that the words borrowed/created not very long time ago do not have such forms. F.e. compare мёд (old word) and йод (more new). It is possible to say выдержанный в меду, but it will be выдержанный в йоде - not йоду for йод.

### The name of the phenomenon

According to [Zalizniak's dictionary](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90._%D0%90._%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0) this phenomenon is called the "2-ой предложный падеж" (second prepositional case). [Russian National Corpus website](http://ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html) calls it "предложный 2", or, in their English version: "locative 2". (Interesting is that *locative* - not *prepositional* - is used as the translation of word предложный for grammatical cases. You can see the "official" list of Russian grammatical cases by clicking "выбрать"/"select" close to the "Грамм. признаки"/"Gramm. features" text box).

All the words that can form locative 2 are marked with the sign **`П₂`** in the Zalizniak's  dictionary.

Here is the excerpt from П₂ definition by Zalizniak:

```
Помета П₂ (за которой может следовать в скобках предлог "в" или "на") - символ
наличия у данного слова особой формы так-называемого 2-го предложного падежа.
...
Помета П₂ означает, что у данного существительного в ед. числе после предлогов 
"в" и "на", выступающих в одном из указанных ниже значений, употребляется особая форма,
отличная от обычного предложного падежа - так называемый 2-ой предложный падеж. Форма 2-го
предложного падежа ед. числа по буквенному составу равна форме Д. ед. того же слова, но 
ударение в ней всегда на окончании. Примеры: "шкаф" (Д. ед. "шкАфу") - П₂ ед. "шкафУ"; 
    ...
```

See [here](http://zaliznyak-dict.narod.ru/c0066.gif), and [here](http://zaliznyak-dict.narod.ru/c0067.gif) the original scanned pages.

### How to find these words

One possibility is to open [the online version of the Zalizniak's dictionary](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Czaliznia%5Cdict&first=74481&encoding=utf-rus) and scan it page by page searching for the mark "п(2)". (For example, look for word "сад" on the page references above). At least this is until a better (for our purposes) version of the online dictionary exists which would allow searching by marks. :-)

Another possibility for finding such words is by using the National Corpus. Click [this](http://ruscorpora.ru/en/search-main.html); click on "select" close to "Gramm. features"; in the following popup check "locative 2". [image]; [image]on the main page click the "search" button. In the results of search you will see the words in locative 2 case put in the context of their usage.

Comment: It is not the answer to the question, it is an explanation of what a prepositional case is. I think you should modify your answer to fit the question better. You may also find [this question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-are-the-lesser-known-russian-cases) interesting.

Comment: @Olga: You have a point. I've made some changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Masculine nouns that have locative:

```
снег в снегу о снеге
дым в дыму о дыме
хвост в хвосте о хвосте
лес в лесу о лесе
бор в бору о боре
бал на балу о бале
плац на плацу о плаце
ров во рву о рве
берег на берегу о береге
мир в миру о мире (here мир means "life outside church", in the meaning of peace and world, locative is not used)
стог в стогу о стоге
долг в долгу о долге
вид на виду о виде
пруд в пруду о пруде
день на дню о дне
нос в носу о носе
глаз в глазу о глазе
таз в тазу о тазе
паз в пазу о пазе
воз на возу о возе
ряд в ряду о ряде
век на веку о веке
строй в строю о строе
бред в бреду о бреде
ветер на ветру о ветре
мел в мелу о меле
тыл в тылу о тыле
пол на полу о поле
пыл в пылу о пыле
бой в бою о бое
ход на ходу о ходе
жар в жару о жаре
стыд в стыду о стыде
быт в быту о быте
пир на пиру о пире
рот во рту о рте
пар на пару о паре
дух на духу о духе 
мост на мосту о мосте
борт на борту о борте
год в году о годе
час в часу о часе
бег на бегу о беге
лёт на лету о лёте (Prepositional is not generally used)
порт в порту о порте
аэропорт в аэропорту об аэропорте
пот в поту о поте
жир в жиру о жире
род в роду о роде
сад в саду о саде
зад в заду о заде
шкаф в шкафу о шкафе
полк при полку о полке
мозг в мозгу о мозге
лёд на льду о льде
сук на суку о суке
раз на разу о разе
рай в раю о рае
угол в углу об угле
бор в бору о боре
свет на свету о свете
вес на весу о весе
дом на дому о доме
гроб в гробу о гробе
чад в чаду о чаде
хлев в хлеву о хлеве
край на краю о крае
вал на валу о вале
повод на поводу о поводе
луг на лугу о луге
бок на боку о боке
мех в меху о мехе
пух в пуху о пухе
пост на посту о посте
скок на скаку о скоке (Prepositional is not generally used)
ад в аду об аде
плот на плоту о плоте
хмель во хмелю о хмеле
верх на верху о верхе
бас на басу о басе
спирт на спирту о спирте
кон на кону о коне
квас на квасу о квасе
```

Masculine proper nouns:

```
Крым в Крыму о Крыме
Клин в Клину о Клине
Дон на Дону о Доне
```

Feminine nouns that have locative (difference in the stress):

```
тень в тенИ о тЕни
грязь в грязИ о грЯзи
пыль в пылИ о пЫли
грудь в грудИ о грУди
сень в сенИ о сЕни
ночь в ночИ о нОчи
даль в далИ о дАли
мель на мелИ о мЕли
сеть в сетИ о сЕти
печь в печИ о пЕчи
кровь в кровИ о крОви
ось на осИ об Оси
рысь на рысИ о рЫси
связь в связИ о свЯзи
тишь в тишИ о тИши
кровь на кровИ о крОви
```

Feminine nouns that have locative forms in plural (difference in the stress and е-ё):

```
слЁзы в слезАх о слЁзах
сОпли в соплЯх о сОплях
слЮни в слюнЯх о слЮнях
Ясли в яслЯх о Яслях
слАсти в сластЯх о слАстях
стрАсти в страстЯх о стрАстях
```