# Dative case in subjects and titles

Tags: дательный-падеж

Why is dative case used in the following for example:

> месяцы в году
>   игры на снегу

There is no sentence, so how can there be an indirect object..

Comment: Dasblinkenlight is absolutely right: it is not dative it is locative case. But even if it was dative (f.e. раздача всем) it is acceptable as a title of article - it is a sentence which consists of subject (подлежащее) with dependent words only, without predicate (сказуемое).

Comment: See [this question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1630/) for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the word forms match dative letter-for-letter, the stress falls on another syllable, giving you a hint that something fishy is going on. Indeed, this is not dative: it is [*locative*](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/405/426), one of a lesser-known cases of Russian nouns. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case#Russian), approximately 150 masculine nouns retain a distinct form for the locative case, used only after "в" and "на". These forms end in "-у́" or "-ю́"
:

> Лежать на снегу.
>
> Стоять на краю.