# Can I use the dative case as a statement of place?

Tags: грамматика

Whilst learning the Russian language I stumbled upon this sentence:

> Хорошо, когда будете в аэропорту в Лондоне, позвони ещё раз.

*Good, when you are at the airport in London, call me again.*

And I'm wondering why it is аэропорт**у** (dativ / masculine)? During my classes I learned that the preposition **в** 99% with the prepositional case. So what do I miss here at this point? I would appreciate any kind of hint, thank you!

Comment: It is not Dative, it is the Locative case. Look here: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/what-are-some-examples-of-nouns-that-end-in-%D1%83-in-prepositional-case/

Comment: You mix plural (будете) and single (позвони). This is only possible if you mean: "When you (and your companions) are at the airport, (you only) call me again". Otherwise, you have to use either both single (будешь, позвони) or plural (будете, позвоните).

Comment: `I learned that the preposition **в** 99% with the prepositional case` Not really. 50% prepositional; 50% accusative.

Comment: @user4419802 : about mixing plural and singular, it's possible when "**будете**" refers to, say, a group with which the individual travels.

Answer (score 2):

There are several dozen nouns, 2nd-declension masculine and overwhelmingly monosyllabic (**аэропорт** is on this list because it mimics the declension of **порт**), that have two propositional forms; a regular **-е** prepositional used with **о**, **при**, and *figurative* instances of **в** and **на** (*Что особенного **в** этом аэропорт**е**? Вполне обыкновенный на вид*), and an **-у** (or **-ю**) prepositional used with **в** and **на** when they *literally* refer to location, as in your example. On a side note, the **-у**/**-ю** ending is always stressed, making it inherently different from dative in many cases. Dative, in fact, has nothing to do with this whatsoever.

This is all you need to know in order to use these forms correctly (apart from the actual word list; that link in the first comment is comprehensive enough, though one always forgets a few when one tries to list them).

And now I'll ramble on a little more about the theoretical stuff.

You might hear the expression "locative case" thrown around, and there's some potential confusion there. What's known in Russian as the "prepositional case" is, historically, the locative case, and it goes by that name in several other Slavic languages.

In Russian, however, we have a non-standard case ending that refers to location, hence it gets called the "locative case". But like I said, there was a time when "prepositional" *was* locative, and then Russian has a limited-use "locative" case *on top of* its locative-renamed-prepositional. The tricky thing here is that while *forms* like **в аэропорту** are archaic, the *distinction* between **в аэропорту** and **в аэропорте** is innovative. In Proto-Slavic, these nouns would either always have an *-u* locative or always have a *-ě* locative (or always have something else entirely), depending on their paradigm, which was much more complicated than the Russian declension we have now. In Russian, the *-ě* (**-е**) ending supplanted all others, but a few leftover *-u* forms remained, and eventually were grammaticalised in a new role as "the *locative* locative", as opposed to the "general" locative now called prepositional.

Comment: Except those nouns are of ***2nd*** declension...

Comment: @VictorBazarov Are they officially now? Because I was taught at one point to swap the 1st and the 2nd because that was how the academics numbered them, as opposed to mere mortals. Zaliznyak's name was mentioned if I remember correctly. I'm the first to agree it's confusing and pointless.

Comment: У Зализняка - "тип склонения", а не "склонение".  "Порт" по-прежнему во втором склонении, а тип склонения 1е...  Или что, уже первое, второе и третье склониния отменили?

Comment: См., например, Викисловарь.

Comment: @VictorBazarov понял, исправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to believe, but this modern word is used with archaic *местный* (locative) case. It is supposed to not exist nowadays but it actually does. Another example, could be *в лесу*. Locative case mostly assimilates (uses same inflection) with prepositional, but for some words - with dative.

Comment: Locative and prepositional were always one and the same; dative has nothing to do with this at all. This isn't an archaic case but the remnant of an archaic *paradigm*, and the literal/figurative distinction of **в лесу** vs. **о лесе** is an innovation that doesn't go back to Proto-Slavic. (Which just had *-u* in the prepositional for some masculine nouns and *-ě* for others, same as it had *-u* in the dative for some masculine nouns and *-ovi* for others.)