# Is there a locative for words not ending in a consonant?

Tags: падежи, существительные

There are some nouns that take the ending *-у* (locative) instead of *-е* (prepositional) after the prepositions *в, на*, like *год, лес, сад*.

**Question:** Is there any such noun which does not end on a consonant?

Comment: The short answer is: No. Have a look at this related question, the discussion there will explain much to you: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/

Comment: But there are some that end on a soft sigh- хмель во хмелю. And soft sign and hard sign were vowels in older Russian.

Comment: @VCH250 - So what? In "older Russian" _absolutely all the words_ ended in a vowel. Besides, what you call "older Russian" wasn't actually Russian, because _ъ_ and _ь_ stopped to be pronounced as vowels in the 12th - 13th centuries, and the Russian language didn't exist back then. The language which was spoken then is properly called Old East Slavic. This question is not about the history of Russian, it's about the present-day state of things.

Comment: @Yellow Sky wow dude, calm down—lol. разслабся, чувак

Comment: Honestly! Chill out, babe, it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

In plural, в слезАх - о слЁзах, в соплЯх - о сОплях, в слюнЯх - о слЮнях, в яслЯх - о Яслях, на снастЯх - о снАстях, в страстЯх - о стрАстях also fixed form на сносЯх.

Comment: на сносях -  I wonder if it can be qualified as locative....

Answer (score -1):

1. Some nouns ending in *-й*, take the ending *-ю* (technically speaking, the yodded *-у*) when indicating location:

e.g. кра**й**, *brink*

на кра**ю**, *at the brink*

Note:
There are different phonemic theories built around Russian; some of them consider the sound "й", or / j /, the jod, to be a semivowel. See p.76 [here](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/bitstream/handle/1887/1839/344_003.pdf?sequence=1).

2. According to [this source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case#Russian), in contemporary Russian...

> "the locative case has largely lost its use as an independent case and
>   became the prepositional case, which is used only after a preposition.
>   The latter is not always used to indicate location, while other cases
>   may also be used to specify location (e.g. the genitive case <...>)."

There are more examples there.

Comment: -1. _В селе_ and _в деле_ are not in the locative case, and they don't end in _-y_. They are in the prepositional case, and it is the locative case ending in _-y_ that the OP asked about. Also, _й_ is not a vowel, so your answer is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to _в селе_ and _в деле_, @Yellow Sky. I've now removed that point from my answer.

Comment: -1, й is a consonant.