# Difference between "где" and "куда"?

Tags: перевод, значения

I believe, где is where? and куда is like, to where? or something like that
I am not sure D:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Откуда` ты идешь? (from) - I am going from my house.

`Куда`ты идешь? (to) - I am going to school.

`Где` эта школа? (location) - The school near your home.

Answer (score 7):

ГДЕ = "Where" (the location) Где яблоко? (where is the apple?—in what location

КУДА = "To where" Куда ты положил яблоко? —where (to where) did you put the apple?

In English we have only "where", which can mean (to where (the action)) and (where(the location)).

Answer (score 1):

It's deeply rooted in Russian grammar. Location without movement governs the locative, while location with movement uses the accusative.

```
Где -> no movement, locative
Куда -> movement, accusative
```

Something similar goes, for instance, in German:

```
wo -> no movement, dative
wohin -> movement, accusative
```

In English movement can be expressed directly with "where to", but often is indicated by other parts of the sentence, or not at all if that's implicitely clear. In Russian you simply must know whether there is movement or not, or else you won't be able to form a proper sentence.

Beside the need to use the proper case, "where" is not the only word that has two variants. For instance, "here" ("from here" / "to here") will also be said differently according to movement.

To show how strong a meaning these adverbs carry, these two sentences are common in Russian:

```
Где ты? -> where are you?
Куда Ты? -> where are you going?
```

While in English the meaning is carried by the verb, in Russian the adverb is sufficient.

Comment: As locative case is mostly outdated nowadays "где" is used usually along the prepositional case except a dozen of words. Probably, it's not a good idea to confuse the beginner with the archaic locative.

Comment: Sorry, that's how I was taught Russian here in France a few decades ago. We were told the locative whas a subcase of the pepositional, with a few exceptions as you said. I did not know the name had fallen in disuse since then.

Comment: Well, it never has gone but has a limited recognition along with a few others. Here the most relevant topic on SE: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-are-the-lesser-known-russian-cases

Answer (score 0):

`Где` means the place itself without action, and `куда` means direction or aim.

Not sure, I'm right, but it seems like you have to manipulate time to male this difference between `где` and `куда` in English.

`Где` maps simple time, and `куда` maps continuous and perfect:

- Где эта улица? - Where is this street?
- Где было молоко? - Where was the milk?
- Куда ты идёшь? - Where are you going?
- Куда ты положил молоко? - Where have you put the milk.

PS: There can be the other meanings of this words, I was answering only about specific case.

Comment: I would say "to where", "to what place" if I really wanted to stress the "куда" meaning in English.

Comment: there are old english words: thence, hence, thither, hither which have similar meanings to  the Russian "where(s)" with movement—отсюда, оттуда, сюда итд