# What old rare case or rule is used in the sentence "выдвигаться в президенты"?

Tags: падежи

I've asked a friend of mine, which is Russian, why they were saying on the news `выдвигаться в президенты` instead of `выдвигаться в президентов`, and he told me it is an exception, of an old case that he couldn't remember at the occasion.

Since then, I've tried to find everywhere what it could be, to no avail.

Would anyone please explain to me what rules are involved in that sentence and why does it make sense?

Comment: Other lesser cases: [What are the lesser known Russian cases?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/404/551).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the so called *lesser cases* in Russian.  This case has many names: второй винительный (second accusative), включительный (inclusive), превратительный (translative), собирательный. From [rusgram.ru](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6):

> Второй винительный падеж (другие названия – включительный,
>   превратительный, собирательный) встречается после предлога `в` при
>   небольшом количестве глаголов, и его окончания совпадают с окончаниями
>   именительного падежа множественного числа (другая трактовка –
>   колебания в одушевлённости): [`пойти`, `записаться`, `выбиться`, `готовиться`,
>   `проситься`, `метить`, `принять`, `выбрать` и т.д. `в`] `солдаты`, `летчики`,
>   `генералы`, `начальники`. За этой формой признаются наименьшие права на
>   статус особого падежа.

This is used after the preposition `в` when somebody receives or seeks some new post or rank: постричься в монахи, баллотироваться в президенты etc.

Comment: So, you're saying it acts just like a regular accusative? Why would they use this one then, rather than the normal accusative?

Comment: @ClaudioDeSouza I added some more explanation.