# Genitive cases ending with -у(in this case, masculine, singular)?

Tags: грамматика, родительный-падеж

[image]

[image]

As far as I know, my Russian teacher never taught me why such things happen... And I've encountered so many cases other than these examples bearing same problems. Can somebody explain when and why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

These are so called *lesser cases* (*малые падежи*). `С боку на бок` - *отложительный падеж*, or *исходный падеж* (ablative).  `Брал меду` - *отделительный падеж*, sometimes also called *количественно-отделительный падеж*.

About lesser cases: [What are the lesser known Russian cases?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-are-the-lesser-known-russian-cases)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer:) But one thing bothers me: I thought that местный падеж is used only when it refers to "где", not suggesting its movement, but I think "с боку на бок" certainly contains movement, and more likely refers to "куда". I'm sorry if I misunderstood :(

Comment: Oh and one more question: if I write "набрал меда(genitive)" or "набрал мед(accusative)", then is it still grammatically correct? I do feel that the latter one is not really proper... or something, though.

Comment: Seems `с боку` is not местный падеж but rather отложительный падеж (аблатив), so I fixed it.  As for your second question, you can say "набрал мед" instead of "набрал меда". However, if you say, for example, "он выпил воду", it means he drank all the offered water, while if you say "он выпил воды", it means he drank part of it.

Comment: *отложительный падеж* - Why??? Russian partitive (отложительный) never reports to the preposition "С". There is typical **ablative** (исходный) in the form "с боку".

Comment: @Morkovkin According to wikipedia, отложительный падеж and аблатив is the same thing.