# Why use the dative "толку" in "От него гораздо больше толку"?

Tags: падежи, genitive-partitive

> От него гораздо больше **толку**, чем от некого короля!

I assume this sentence literally means:

> From him (we get) a lot more **use** than from a certain king.

I wonder why the noun "толк" has to be in Dative here? Is it an omitted, impersonal subject that I'm dealing with here? Still, I'm not sure how to properly parse the sentence.

Comment: Literally one can say something like: This person (male) is more useful, more efficient, rational or practical (and probably more clever) than some king, and this is beneficial to other people . _толку_ does not necessarily imply USE but all these connotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not dative. It's a genitive form from a now-extinct paradigm that has come to have a partitive meaning, "a measure of an uncountable thing". Related: [Partitive Genitive](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/partitive-genitive).

Comment: Wow, I hadn't expected this. So is it like "he is **of** a lot more use ..."?

Comment: @alone-Zee Your original "from him (we get)" was a closer approximation. It's the same use of genitive as the French *je voudrais **de** l'eau*, "I'd like [a quantity] of water" = "some water".

Comment: Oh, so it's a bit strange in English, but is it like: "a lot more ***of*** use"? --- "a measure {***a lot more***} **of** an uncountable thing {***use***}"

Comment: @alone-Zee Yes, exactly.

Comment: @alone-Zee the form of standard Genitive ***толкА*** here would also be OK

Comment: In this sense толкУ seems preferable (cf. без толку - fixed phrase, толку мало, толку нет - sound better)