# case of поездки in expression в всей поездки

Tags: падежи

In expression в всей поездки I think всей is in the prepositional case. But what case is поездки?

Comment: Can you please give a full sentence? I am afraid the preposition is wrong and perhaps the case

Comment: It's locative case. See related question: [What are the lesser known Russian cases?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-are-the-lesser-known-russian-cases)

Answer (score 1):

"В всей поездки" is ungrammatical. Did you mean "во всей поездке"? Then it's Locative. Could also be Genitive: "(из) всей поездки".

See the declension charts for [весь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) and [поездка](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Comment: Note that because “поездке” sounds exactly like “поездки”, it’s a common mistake among native speakers to write the latter when they intended the former. (In the same vein, they often write “едим” instead of “едем”, and hilarity sometimes ensues.)