# Location - dative or prepositional case?

Tags: падежи

В носу́ - дательный, в голове́ - дательный или предложный? Is there a rule for this usage?

Comment: nope, you are supposed to memories some  special usages like "в носу"

Comment: It looks like one syllable words go with dative. On the other hand, how do you distinguish dative and prepositional? They are the same. Даю голове, думаю о голове. Maybe it's just dative, period.

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Why is the downgrade?

Comment: @user1602: I didn't downvote it, but the premise of your question (*в носу́ - дательный*) is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

В носу, в голове is the prepositional case.
In the old days it was a separate case, the locative case (местный падеж). Then it was combined with the prepositional case, because most of the forms were the same (о голове - в голове).
But not all of them were the same! These forms in modern Russian are a special group of the prepositional case: в лесу, в снегу, в раю, в носу, на двери, на краю.

Their differences are as follows:

- The ending -у/-ю (-и for feminine nouns like дверь).
- The preposition в/на; by this feature they can be distinguished from the dative - the dative is never combined with these prepositions.
- The accent is always on the end; by this feature they also can be distinguished from the dative: к лЕсу (dat.) - в лесУ (prep. loc.).
- Their meaning is different from that of the standard prepositional form: в мИре (prep.) =/= в мирУ (prep. loc.), на крАе (prep.) =/= на краЮ (prep. loc.).

Comment: Я думаю о носу или о носе?

Comment: "Their differences are as follows:... - The preposition в/на". In your example, the preposition O. This is the preposition for the standard prepositional case with the ending -е (о носе). The locative form - в носу.

Comment: I only know 6 cases in modern Russian, what's locative? Can a noun have two different forms in the same grammatical case? Are you saying в носу́ и о но́се are both forms of the prepositional case?

Comment: Please read my main answer again and you will know what a locative is. Yes, it can. В носу and о носе are  both forms of the prepositional case.

Comment: @user1602: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-are-the-lesser-known-russian-cases?rq=1

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but I need authorative references, like the Russian ministry of education, Moscow university linguistic department, etc.

Comment: @user1602
http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6#231:~:text=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85.-,1.2%20%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9,%2C%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%C3%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%C3%A9%D0%BD%D0%B8).,-%D0%92%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE

Comment: Это преподают в средней школе?