# Why чаю, not чая, in "мы предлагаем гостям чашку чаю"?

Tags: перевод, грамматика, падежи

I understand the translation of **Мы предлагаем гостям чашку чаю** to be "We offer a cup of tea to guests".

But if this is so, shouldn't **чай** be in the genitive case (**чая**)? Why is it **чаю**?

Perhaps I'm interpreting the sentence incorrectly, or there is a nuanced grammar rule at play here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Чаю vs. чая: what ending is correct?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/194/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%8e-vs-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f-what-ending-is-correct)

Comment: There was a similar topic on http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/662/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E .

Comment: The answers in the other questions are in Russian, which is difficult for beginners in Russian like myself. I could use a translation tool but I worry about imprecise results. That said, go ahead and close the question if it's considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Translation of an [answer in Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/196/551))

This is an example of [Partitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive) ([частичного падежа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)). It is rarely used in Russian, usually with nouns that mean food or drinks.

> Выпить воды (not all the water, but some water)
>
> Поесть хлеба (some bread)
>
> Выпить коньяку (some cognac)

Partitive usually matches Genitive case, but most masculine nouns like чай (tea), коньяк (cognac), бензинчик (gasoline), etc., have two forms of Partitive:  чая/чаю, коньяка/коньяку, бензинчика/бензинчику. Both variants are correct, but second one (that matches Dative case) is colloquial.

So, in second case, in a sentence

> Можно мне ещё чая/чаю?

Both variants are correct, because Partitive is used. However in case of "Я бы не отказался от чашки чая" the noun should be in Genitive case and so the correct form should be

> Я бы не отказался от чашки чая.

Answer (score 2):

Both "чашку чаю" and "чашку чая" are correct. The difference is that "чаю" is a spoken variant and "чая" is a stylistically neutral one.

Answer (score 2):

Using the genitive in a partitive sense (kind of like "some..") is not that uncommon, but special partitive forms in -у are used less & less often these days. An American textbook in the 1970s ("Making Progress in Russian") listed about twenty words with -у partitive endings; most books now don't bother bringing it up, with the possible exception of чаю, which is still used, and народу (as in много народу). For a sense of this you can play with Google's ngram viewer: here's a comparison of [много народу vs. много народа](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=12&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0).